# Search XML value by attribute name with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML file like:

```
<ListOfMegaCities>                
    <MegaCities city="Moscow" residents="11503501" foundation="1624"/>
    <MegaCities residents="8336817" city="New York" foundation="1147"/>
    <MegaCities foundation="1066"  residents="8961989" city="London"/>
</ListOfMegaCities>
```

I want to search in each line for attribute name like "city" and parse the value like "New York".
The order of value + attributes should not matter in xml file.

I know it look very simple...but I dont get it.

I try it like:

```
strCityValue = ChildNodes[iIndex].Attributes[1].Value;
```

But for this solution the order of values must be fixed in the xml file...

Comment: Use the [XElement.Attribute(XName) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.GetAttribute(...)` is your friend; for example:

```cs
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"<ListOfMegaCities>
    <MegaCities city=""Moscow"" residents=""11503501"" foundation=""1624""/>
    <MegaCities residents=""8336817"" city=""New York"" foundation=""1147""/>
    <MegaCities foundation=""1066""  residents=""8961989"" city=""London""/>
</ListOfMegaCities>");
foreach (XmlElement city in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("MegaCities"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(city.GetAttribute("city"));
}
```

or with `XDocument`, `.Attribute(...)`:

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<ListOfMegaCities>
    <MegaCities city=""Moscow"" residents=""11503501"" foundation=""1624""/>
    <MegaCities residents=""8336817"" city=""New York"" foundation=""1147""/>
    <MegaCities foundation=""1066""  residents=""8961989"" city=""London""/>
</ListOfMegaCities>");
foreach (XElement city in doc.Root.Elements("MegaCities"))
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)city.Attribute("city"));
}
```